# Group Rows in group by though it contains NULL value in mysql / postgres

Tags: mysql

I have a table from where I am getting month names and some quantity measures.

Table Name = Month_Name

```
SELECT month_name,q1,q2 FROM month_name;
mysql> SELECT * FROM MONTH;
+------------+------+------+
| month_name | q1   | q2   |
+------------+------+------+
| January    |   10 |   20 |
| March      |   30 |   40 |
| March      |   10 |    5 |
+------------+------+------+
```

Expected Output:

```
mysql> SELECT month_name ,SUM(q1),SUM(q2) FROM MONTH GROUP BY month_name;
+------------+---------+---------+
| month_name | sum(q1) | sum(q2) |
+------------+---------+---------+
| January    |      10 |      20 |
| Febuary    |       0 |       0 |
| March      |      40 |      45 |
| April      |      0  |      0  |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

Group by month will not print February and April since these 2 months are not present in base table.  I do not want to use Union All since there will be performance issues with union All, Is there any other optimised approach to this.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Why not May? Or December?

Comment: Also, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a calendar table which keeps track of all the month names which you want to appear in your report.

```
SELECT
    m1.month_name,
    SUM(q1) AS q1_sum,
    SUM(q2) AS q2_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT 'January' AS month_name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'February' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'March' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 'December'
) m1
LEFT JOIN month m2
    ON m1.month_name = m2.month_name
GROUP BY
    m1.month_name;
```

Note that while this solve your immediate problem, it is still not ideal, because we don't have any easy way to sort the months.  A much better table design would be to maintain a date column.  The month name is easily derived from the date.